# Date split in linux using awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Date split/conversion in linux using awk.

input

```
19-AUG-10 05.56.48 PM
```

desired output

```
20100819T17:56:48
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU awk:

```
echo "19-AUG-10 05.56.48 PM" | awk -F- '{ gsub(/\./,":");system("date -d\"" $2"-"$1"-"$3 "\" +%Y%m%dT%H:%M:%S")}'
```